# JavaScript - dynamic SVG - onload attribute - event not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, svg, setinterval, onload

#### Inserting dynamic SVG content into the DOM does not work as expected, having the SVG element onload attribute (containing JavaScript) regarding: "setInterval()".

As noted in the search tags of this question; this is plain (valilla) JavaScript (not jQuery); here's a breakdown of the issue:

- I have some SVG code (plain text) that gets inserted into a `<div>` as `innerHTML`
- the SVG element has an `onload` attribute with some JavaScript inside it
- the JavaScript contains `setInterval(...)` - (which does not work at all)
- I grab the SVG element from the temporary div and return it as the result of a function.
- this result is appended into some element in the live DOM (body)

**the strange issue:**

- any other code inside that `onload` attribute works fine,
- only `setInterval` & `setTimeout` is completely ignored

### More info:

During runtime (start-up), the SVG code is grabbed from an existing `embed` element `.getSVGDocument()` (after it has loaded) and prepared as plain HTML which can just be used as a template to create many others from the same source-code. I'm not using `cloneNode(true)` -because: the interval is for animation (continuous *slow & smooth* rotation) - which could have a heavy impact on client-side resources, hence, I thought it best to grab the code and keep it as template - then remove the original from the DOM.

With all the above in mind, everything works fine:

- The (new) SVG shows up on screen, all nice and dandy-like
- When I `console.log` the (inline) SVG code that is used, all looks perfect
- I get no errors, and there is no error handler that mutes errors (`window.onerror == null`)
- The JavaScript (text) inside the SVG node's `onload` attribute works for things like: `console.log(this)` - (which produces the SVG element in the log) - however, as mentioned: `setInterval()` & `setTimeout()` is just simply ignored - without any error and no warning.

The following code is a very short example, and (regrettably) it works; however, in my production app it doesn't.

### The code:

```
var html = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" onload="setInterval(function(){ console.log(\'testing\'); },500);">';
var temp = document.createElement('div');  temp.innerHTML = html;
var node = temp.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

document.body.appendChild(node);
```

If you test the above code in a new js file, it works; however, for the life of me I can't find the reason why it breaks in my app; as explained, it's quite simple really.

### The question:

Does anyone know if there is some "gotcha" I'm not aware of regarding this? Maybe name-spacing?

If the source-code is required, I can load it up on JSFiddle, or CodePen -if required, but, it's a lot of code, and many files, which may not be necessary for publication.

I'm sure it's just something small; like, how timers register according to scope, and maybe how it's affected in `.bind()` ?

I'm really stuck with this, and I kinda need it working for a good impression for a job-interview; so if you know anything that could help, I would appreciate your input very much.

Thank you.

Comment: If you declare the function with setInterval in your HTML, and call it from the SVG's onload, does it work? Have you tried multiple browsers, as this could be a bug?

Comment: @Tibo :: I'm not sure I understand, but, the function that returns the new SVG object just grabs the "prepared" SVG code (plain text) -> create a DOM node from it (SVG) -> and returns this node.  The JavaScript code  (onload) should remain inside the SVG file though as it should be edited by another developer, having what should be together - in the same place.  I have tested this with Chrome, FireFox & Opera, all 3 fails exactly the same way - no error - just not working as expected, so, It must be some simple (and standard) thing I'm missing.

Comment: @Tibo yes, it works; tried this simple usecase in Fx and Chrome. In Fx you don't even need to append node into body. `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<!doctype html></body><script>var temp=document.createElement('div');%0Atemp.innerHTML='<svg onload="console.log(\'onoad\');setInterval(function(){ console.log(\'interval\'); },500);">';var node = temp.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];document.body.appendChild(node);</script>`

Comment: Guys, I just found the issue - and a fix; see, the SVG file is in an `<embed>` element, and runs once (on start), but gets removed, so synchronous code works. The issue is: the new element's `onload` event is not getting triggered. so, as a fix, I just use the onload JS to set a property of `this`, and in the parent document (function), I test if that is set, if not - boom, - `onload` did not fire on the new element, so I manually trigger it.  Still though, it would be nice to know why the `onload` works for the example above @myf, but not in my app - as they are almost exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe if someone can post an answer about a "general rule of thumb" -or something that could fix such things for others related to this kind of thing, I'll gladly up-vote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### embedded content, onload attributes & the DOM

The following may help in related scenarios:

- when targeting an asynchronous source, make sure the `contentDocument` or `getSVGDocument()` contains the resources you need to access. The `window.onload`, or the `DOMContentLoaded` event is relative to the current DOM, so it may help constructing your own listener->trigger for a cross-browser solution, because the contents you need may not be ready in a synchronous fashion.
- the `onload` attribute/event is not triggered when inserting dynamic content that is not asynchronously loaded, but may fire under certain circumstances, so, again, a custom:
  listen->trigger will solve that.

### question specific

The question is directly related to the 2nd point above, and the answer is quite simple really:

- in the "onload" attribute of said SVG, set a simple value as property of **this** like:
  `<svg onload="this.ready = true; setTinterval(...)"`
- in the constructor function, after the element was dynamically created, simply check if the svg-node's `onload` event was fired like so:
  `if (!svgNode.ready){ svgNode.onload(); }`

If there is an error in your code, but no error is shown, make sure `window.onerror` is either **null** -or if it's a function, make sure it does NOT return `true` - else it may suppress errors and you'll have a hard time tracking down what's wrong.

Please feel free to either improve this answer, or comment and I'll improve it accordingly; however, better answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

**6 years later...**

With vanilla JavaScript Web Components you can do:

```html
<load-svg></load-svg>

<script>
  customElements.define("load-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<svg></svg>`;
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log("testing");
      }, 500);
    }
  });
</script>
```