# Can you make a simple call to an external javascript file inside an SVG, onload?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, external

I have a SVG image. I would like to program that SVG image to call an external javascript file when it loads. I have tried a few different strategies and none of them have worked. I feel the closest I have gotten is by putting creating an alert in an onload function in the `<svg>` tag.

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="474.000000pt" height="316.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 474.000000 316.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" onload="alert(2)">
```

The alert in the onload box works, but I'm not sure if you can call upon some external javascript code inside those quotes. Ideally, that is what I would do.

I have also tried adding a standard `<script src="https://mycode.js"></script>` tag right under the beginning `<svg>` tag but before the `<g transform=.....` and that doesn't work either. I can call an alert, and that will work, but not an external script. The shortest/simplest solution is pretty important in this scenario too.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I was able to solve my first problem, which was that I couldn't get any request sent out in the first place. I am able to send a request out now onload.
`<svg onload="const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open('GET', 'https://external.js');xhr.send(null);">`

So now it's 'GET'ing the external JS file but not loading/triggering it on the other end (because it's not requesting it as a script source). Any way to use this base to request it as a script source?

SOLVED:

The working code is:

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="474.000000pt" height="316.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 474.000000 316.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" onload="function loadScript( url ) {let script = document.createElement('script') 
script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = url; document.head.appendChild(script); 
} loadScript('https://external.js')">
```

Comment: I am assuming you own that external script?

If that is the case you can just check via a querySelector if your SVG shows in the DOM and then do whatever javascript logic you want to execute.

Comment: Are you waiting for the script's load event, or the document's load event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - dynamic SVG - onload attribute - event not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283418/javascript-dynamic-svg-onload-attribute-event-not-triggered)

Comment: @niklasbec I'd just like to make a request when the SVG loads. <svg onload="external javascript reference/request here ideally"> My goal is just to get a request sent out, the javascript file that I'd like to reference just needs an external endpoint to trigger it, and ideally my SVG would do that.

Comment: How is this svg loaded exactly? Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would try:

```
function loadScript( url ) {
  let script = document.createElement( "script" )
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = url;
     document.head.appendChild(script); 
}

//Set the event listener, in this case vue:

<svg onload="loadScript('https://mycode.js')" />
```

If you are not using vue or react or something similar you need to add the onload function with a querySelector or something.

Comment: I'll work on this for a bit, thank you.

Comment: Bro, you're literally an absolute genius. After a bit of messing with it, I got it to work. I've updated it to show the final result.